# Image response for query from android app in api.ai

Tags: android, dialogflow-es

with bit of struggle I managed to build my android chat app which interacts with api.ai agent. I am stuck at a point where I am unable to make the agent provide an image response to the android app. Is this possible to achieve? Your help is greatly appreciated.

regards
khan

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.